# Сложность с подключением к удаленному ПК "из под микротика"

Tags: маршрутизация, mikrotik

Помогите пожалуйста советом. Есть два офиса, расположены в разных районах. На каждом офисе стоит микротик. Настраивались они одинаково. Проблема состоит в следующем: Из офиса №1 не могу получить доступ к удаленному ПК (по ssh) который установлен на офисе №2. На миротике (офис№2) порт проброшен. Из другой сети (например находясь дома) подключение к удаленному ПК на офисе №2 проходит без проблем. А вот "из под микротика" на офисе №1 подключится не получается.

Возможно между микротиками должна быть какая-то особенная настройка что бы они могли "работать с друг другом". Ведь из другого интернета (без микротика) все работает нормально. Пробовал отключать правила в файрволле, пробовал добавлять IP-адрес (офис№1) в список разрешенных, пробрасовывал порт индивидуально для IP-адреса (офис№1), никаких результатов не дало. Даже пинг с микротика (офис№1) не проходит на мироктик (офис№2).

Возможно упускают какую-то мелочь. К сожалению большого опыта в работе с микротиком еще нет. Многие моменты еще не понятны.

**Основные настройки на миротике (офис №2) следующие:**

```
/interface bridge
add name=bridge1
```

```
/interface bridge port
add bridge=bridge1 interface=ether2
add bridge=bridge1 interface=ether3
add bridge=bridge1 interface=ether4
add bridge=bridge1 interface=ether5
```

```
/ip address
add address=192.168.88.1/24 interface=bridge1 network=192.168.88.0
```

```
/ip firewall nat 
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat out-interface=ether1
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat dst-port=30100 in-interface=ether1 in-interface-list=all protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.88.100 to-ports=30100
```

```
/ip firewall filter
add action=accept chain=input connection-state=established
add action=accept chain=forward connection-state=established
add action=accept chain=input connection-state=related
add action=accept chain=forward connection-state=related
add action=accept chain=input in-interface=ether1 src-address=192.168.88.0/24
add action=accept chain=forward in-interface=bridge1 out-interface=ether1
add action=add-src-to-address-list address-list=DNS_FLOOD address-list-timeout=none-dynamic chain=input dst-port=53 in-interface=ether1 protocol=udp
add action=drop chain=input dst-port=53 in-interface=ether1 protocol=udp
add action=drop chain=input disabled=yes protocol=icmp
add action=drop chain=forward protocol=icmp
add action=drop chain=input connection-state=invalid disabled=yes
add action=drop chain=forward connection-state=invalid disabled=yes
add action=drop chain=input disabled=yes in-interface=ether1
add action=drop chain=forward disabled=yes
add action=accept chain=input disabled=yes
```

```
/ip service
set telnet disabled=yes
set ftp disabled=yes
set www address=192.168.88.0/24
set ssh disabled=yes
set api disabled=yes
set winbox address=192.168.88.0/24
set api-ssl disabled=yes
```

**Маршруты** (/ip route> print)
*Оба микротика работают от одного и того же провайдера интернета. Но подключение у каждого свое (это не общая сеть предприятия и т.д)*

**(Микротик Офис №1)**

```
     DST-ADDRESS        PREF-SRC        GATEWAY            DISTANCE
ADS  0.0.0.0/0                          194.44.99.254             1
ADC  194.44.99.0/24     194.44.99.10    ether1                    0
ADC  192.168.88.0/24    192.168.88.1    bridge1                   0
```

**(Микротик Офис №2)**

```
     DST-ADDRESS        PREF-SRC        GATEWAY            DISTANCE
ADS  0.0.0.0/0                          194.44.99.254             1
ADC  194.44.99.0/24     194.44.99.91    ether1                    0 
ADC  192.168.88.0/24    192.168.88.1    bridge1                   0
```

Comment: Маршруты с обоих микротиков покажи)

Comment: Спасибо что отписали. Добавил маршруты (/ip route> print)  в главную тему (в конце поста).

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего изоляция клиентов на провайдере. Локальная сеть для юрлиц у многих провайдеров это отдельная услуга, а с такой топологией она никак не контролируется. так вот чтоб её не контролировать включили изоляцию адресов. Наверное адреса даже не пингются.

Можно попробовать исправить топологию добавив маршруты

```
194.44.99.91/32 gateway 194.44.99.254
```

Но скорее всего надо пообщаться с Вашим провайдером.